# Is there an option to make MathJax code recoverable from rendered SVG?

Tags: mathjax

What I am looking for is a way, either built in or a hack, that makes me able to go from

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="6.877ex" height="2.843ex" style="vertical-align: -0.838ex;" viewBox="0 -863.1 2960.9 1223.9" role="img" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
    <path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMAIN-28" d="M94 250Q94 319 104 381T127 488T164 576T202 643T244 695T277 729T302 750H315H319Q333 750 333 741Q333 738 316 720T275 667T226 581T184 443T167 250T184 58T225 -81T274 -167T316 -220T333 -241Q333 -250 318 -250H315H302L274 -226Q180 -141 137 -14T94 250Z"></path>
    <path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMATHI-61" d="M33 157Q33 258 109 349T280 441Q331 441 370 392Q386 422 416 422Q429 422 439 414T449 394Q449 381 412 234T374 68Q374 43 381 35T402 26Q411 27 422 35Q443 55 463 131Q469 151 473 152Q475 153 483 153H487Q506 153 506 144Q506 138 501 117T481 63T449 13Q436 0 417 -8Q409 -10 393 -10Q359 -10 336 5T306 36L300 51Q299 52 296 50Q294 48 292 46Q233 -10 172 -10Q117 -10 75 30T33 157ZM351 328Q351 334 346 350T323 385T277 405Q242 405 210 374T160 293Q131 214 119 129Q119 126 119 118T118 106Q118 61 136 44T179 26Q217 26 254 59T298 110Q300 114 325 217T351 328Z"></path>
    <path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMAIN-2B" d="M56 237T56 250T70 270H369V420L370 570Q380 583 389 583Q402 583 409 568V270H707Q722 262 722 250T707 230H409V-68Q401 -82 391 -82H389H387Q375 -82 369 -68V230H70Q56 237 56 250Z"></path>
    <path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMATHI-62" d="M73 647Q73 657 77 670T89 683Q90 683 161 688T234 694Q246 694 246 685T212 542Q204 508 195 472T180 418L176 399Q176 396 182 402Q231 442 283 442Q345 442 383 396T422 280Q422 169 343 79T173 -11Q123 -11 82 27T40 150V159Q40 180 48 217T97 414Q147 611 147 623T109 637Q104 637 101 637H96Q86 637 83 637T76 640T73 647ZM336 325V331Q336 405 275 405Q258 405 240 397T207 376T181 352T163 330L157 322L136 236Q114 150 114 114Q114 66 138 42Q154 26 178 26Q211 26 245 58Q270 81 285 114T318 219Q336 291 336 325Z"></path>
    <path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMAIN-29" d="M60 749L64 750Q69 750 74 750H86L114 726Q208 641 251 514T294 250Q294 182 284 119T261 12T224 -76T186 -143T145 -194T113 -227T90 -246Q87 -249 86 -250H74Q66 -250 63 -250T58 -247T55 -238Q56 -237 66 -225Q221 -64 221 250T66 725Q56 737 55 738Q55 746 60 749Z"></path>
</defs>
<g stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)">
     <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMAIN-28" x="0" y="0"></use>
     <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMATHI-61" x="389" y="0"></use>
     <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMAIN-2B" x="1141" y="0"></use>
     <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMATHI-62" x="2141" y="0"></use>
     <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMAIN-29" x="2571" y="0"></use>
</g>
</svg>
```

to

```
\left(a+b\right)
```

The SVG is self generated so I would like have a map that that identifies with each SVG symbol (or group of symbols) a character in the string.
I thought of something like class annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Your question indicates that you are looking to reconstruct TeX input from MathJax output, in which case the answer is "no".

On the one hand, MathJax converts input into (essentially) MathML in its internal data structure and renders that; cf. http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/model.html#the-components-of-mathjax. While you can reconstruct that MathML in many cases, you can't reconstruct the original TeX from it (for SVG, the default configuration makes it even harder).

On the other hand, even TeX-like rendering tools (like MathJax's predecessor jsMath) will have to resolve macros down to a TeX-like internal format (TeX lists basically) in which case you could only regenerate some very basic layout instructions (because real TeX/LaTeX is a programming language for print layout).

Of course, MathJax provides APIs to retrieve the original input from a given element and, in fact, stores it in the DOM in a custom script tag right after the SVG; so if that's what you're after it's much simpler.

Finally, if all you want to know is what Unicode point a certain SVG path represents, then the `href` of the `<use>` elements is what you're after, e.g., `#E1-MJMAIN-28` matches `u+0028`.